# Applying ArcPy SpatialJoin_analysis in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join

I'm trying to implement the same solution as ArcPy's `SpatialJoin_analysis` in GeoPandas.

I have one shapefile which contains Polygons and Multipolygons. I need to perform below spatial operation of ArcPy using open-source `GeoPandas` library.

```py
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(
    target_features=spatial_join_in,
    join_features=spatial_join_in,
    out_feature_class=spatial_join_out,
    join_operation="JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE",
    join_type="KEEP_ALL",
    field_mapping="#",
    match_option="ARE_IDENTICAL_TO"
)
```

*The Same shapefile is passed as both spatial_join_in files.*

This operation also adds `Join Count` in each row, which is later used to filter the density areas.

How can we achieve similar [solution](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) using [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/index.html)?

Comment: This really needs a simple, hard-coded input dataframe and an explicit description of the desired output.